# RSA padding decryption problem (chat application)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, chat

I am writeing code for chat app in Java and I must implement cryptography algorithms. I am using RSA, every user have own keys. When one user send message to other user, app will encrypt message and write cipher in .txt file. Then, app will read that .txt file, decrypt file and show decrypted cipher...but I have error

```
> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:383)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:294)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at org.fastchat.User.readMessage(User.java:139)
    at org.fastchat.ChatWith.<init>(ChatWith.java:80)
    at org.fastchat.WatchInbox.startWatch(WatchInbox.java:75)
    at org.fastchat.WatchInbox.run(WatchInbox.java:41)
```

I checked keys and message, can you tell me something more about this problem?
Function for encrypt and write message in inbox

```
public void sendMessage(User receiver, String message) throws Exception {
    //Encrypter message, sent to receiver inbox
    // Getting the public key from the key pair
    PublicKey publicKey = receiver.getPub();

    // Creating a Cipher object
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

    // Initializing a Cipher object
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    // Add data to the cipher
    byte[] input = message.getBytes();
    cipher.update(input);

    // encrypting the data
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal();
//      System.out.println(new String(cipherText, "UTF8")); 

    BufferedWriter recFile=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(receiver.getInbox()+"/"+getUsername()+".txt"));
    recFile.write(new String(cipherText,"UTF8"));


    //DONT DELETE
    //Make check file in receiver check folder, inbox check
    BufferedWriter check=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(receiver.getCheck()+"/"+getUsername()+".txt"));
    Random random=new Random();
    Integer num=random.nextInt(20);
    check.write(num.toString());

    check.close();
    recFile.close();
}
```

This is a function for decrypt and read message

```
    public String readMessage(String msg) throws Exception{
    // Creating a Cipher object

    System.out.println("\n\n"+msg+"\n");     //!!!!!
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

    // Initializing the same cipher for decryption
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPriv());

    // Decrypting the text
    byte[] decipheredText = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes());
    return new String(decipheredText,"UTF8");   
}
```

Can I encrypt/decrypt with RSA algorithm only using .txt file or I must use some additional methods?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to base 64 encode your ciphertext if you want to treat it as text. A ciphertext consists of random valued bytes, and not every bytes represents a valid character.

```
recFile.write(new String(cipherText,"UTF8"));
```

Both the `new String` in the above line and the `getBytes` in the decryption procedure may cause bytes to be dropped, changed or even inserted.

---

Using UTF-8 as encoding strategy for actual bytes is a good idea. Currently you are using the platform encoding for the plaintext message:

```
byte[] input = message.getBytes();
```

That's not a good idea, use `message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. By specifying the character set that way you also avoid unnecessary exception handling as above character sets are always present, so correctness is verified during compile time.

Comment: First, I made this correction  `byte[] input = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); ` , nothing happen, after that I made this `byte[] decipheredText = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` ,nothing again, I get same error.